# Extracting data from one column and storing in another based on a condition

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, sum, pivot

The data I have looks like below-

```
ID      category     Type_1     Type_2     Match?      Quantity
123       1            A          B       no match        2
123       2            A          B       no match        1
123       3            A          B       no match        6
123       4            A          B       no match        6
123       5            A          B       no match        9
123       6            A          B       no match        1
456       1            A          A        match          6
456       2            A          A        match          4
456       3            A          A        match          4
456       4            A          A        match          3
456       5            A          A        match          0
456       6            A          A        match          1
```

I want to restructure this table by doing the following-

1) When the **category is 3**, I want to create another column **cat_3** and store the **Type_2** for **category 3** underneath that. Create another column **Quantity_3** and store the quantity **corresponding to 3** underneath that.

2) For **all other categories other than 3**, I want to create another column **Other_categories** and store **Type_1** corresponding to **other categories** underneath that. Create another column **Quantity_for_other_categories** and store the **sum of quantities corresponding to all other categories** underneath that.

The result should look like below-

```
ID    cat_3     Quantity_3     Other_categories   Quantity_for_other_categories    Match?
123     B           6                 A                       19                   no match
456     A           4                 A                       14                   match
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, cat_3, Quantity_3, Other_categories, Quantity_for_other_categories, Match
FROM (
  SELECT id, 
    Type_2 AS cat_3,
    Quantity AS Quantity_3,
    Match
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE category = 3
  ORDER BY id
) FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT id, 
    Type_1 AS  Other_categories,
    SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity_for_other_categories,  
    Match
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE category != 3
  GROUP BY id, Type_1, Match
)
USING(id, Match)
-- ORDER BY id
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row id  cat_3   Quantity_3  Other_categories    Quantity_for_other_categories   Match    
1   123 B       6           A                   19                              no match     
2   456 A       4           A                   14                              match
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional aggregation. Assuming that `type_1`, `type_2` and `match` are fixed for each `id`, you could do:

```
select 
    id,
    type_2 cat_3,
    sumif(quantity, category = 3) quantity_3,
    type_1 other_categories,
    sumif(quantity, category <> 3) quantity_for_other_catgories,
    match
from mytable
group by id, type_2, type_1, match
```